# Cannot impersonate service account to create calendar events

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client, service-accounts

I'm trying to implement user impersonation with a google service account and have been having problems for a while, this is the code I am using in Java:

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential
        .fromStream(TestGoogleCalendarEventCreate.class
            .getResourceAsStream("/ph3-rovigo-313910-6094af96ccfc.json"))
        .createScoped(CalendarScopes.all()).createDelegated("no-reply@dutytree.it");
```

When I try to read the events from a shared calendar, I receive the following authenication error:

> com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
> POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

If I don't use impersonation, I am able to read the events but I can't invite attendees to newly created events.
The service account has domain-wide authority enabled in a G-Suite domain
as in the follwing screenshot. The clieint id is the client id of the service account user. Do I need other permission to be granted on any user?

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using `setServiceAccountUser`

```
 GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
      .setTransport(httpTransport)
      .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
      .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
      .setServiceAccountScopes(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USERS)
      .setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)
      .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
          new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
      .build();
```

Comment: I tried this way too, with CalendarScopes.all(), but with no luck. Always receive error 401 in the authentication phase.

Comment: I think you should check your delegation then.

Answer (score 0):

In my case following works:

Make sure that you delegate domain-wide authority to ALL scopes requested in `createScoped(...)`.

In the case above you use `.createScoped(CalendarScopes.all())` that contains `calendar.settings.readonly` you do not provide authority for.

Replace it with:

```
.createScoped(ImmutableList.of(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR, CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_EVENTS))
.createDelegated("no-reply@dutytree.it")
```